# ACF or PACF decaying up to lag 50 or more, how to interpret?

Tags: autocorrelation, acf-pacf

A few times I saw ACFs or PACFs of lag around 50, and it was decaying. But all the 50 were significantly different from 0.

Can I conclude it shall be an AR(50) or MA(50) model? Or what is the approach in those cases?

Comment: Often when you see this the series is non-stationary in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

For non-seasonal data if the ACF is dominant then the order of the AR model is the last significant PACF value ...reverse this logic to asses the order of the MA model If you tons of significant ACF and PACF it is either a seasonal model or a model with strong deterministic structure like trends ...

Only your data knows for sure .. post it and I will try and help further.